# Qt unable to allocate high memory

Tags: qt, windows-7

I am using Qt to write an FTP Application , whenever I use a small file ...it works fine but when I use large file size (200 MB) Qt crashes by displaying message

"unable to alloc 405769344 bytes
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
QObject::killTimers: timers cannot be stopped from another thread."

What changes are needed for Qt to support large memory allocations on Windows 7. Any suggestions would be helpful...Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @ExpatEgghead Windows 7...

Comment: Have you tried to build Qt yourself with -largefile? Also, show the code please.

Comment: Allocating 386MB RAM on the heap in one chunk can fail easily, that's generic computing issue, not Qt or C++-specific. Your FTP client shouldn't really load everything into memory in one go, but do the I/O incrementally.

Comment: Well, QT does support large memory allocations. Some code will be needed.

Comment: yes @ExpatEgghead thats the code Iam looking for

Answer (score 2):

Qt has in its bag 
QFtp::put ( QIODevice * dev, const QString & file, TransferType type = Binary ) 
data is read in chunks from the IO device, so this overload allows to transmit large amounts of data without the need to read all the data into memory at once,
Previously I was using 
QFtp::put ( const QByteArray & data, const QString & file, TransferType type = Binary )
and hence the code crashed for large files while allocating memory.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Even if you could figure out how to store 300MB of data on the heap (which is a waste of computing power for that kind of application), at some point some user will download 4GB of data crashing it again. A chunk oriented approach is much better and makes the application run smoothly especially on exit.